# Why database contraints in HSQLDB are only checked during a commit when using transactions in Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hsqldb

I spotted an odd behavior in HSQL, it seems when using database transactions database contraints are not checked during SQL inserts but during SQL commits and when a transaction it is rollbacked they are not checked at all.

I have a Spring integration test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true, transactionManager="transactionManager")
@Transactional
public class IntegrationTest {
```

with a test that creates a new entity instance and calls Hibernate's `persist` on it.

It works fine, however when I change `defaultRollback` to `false` it fails:

```
Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@517a2b0] to process 'after' execution for test: method [public void MyIntegrationTest.test()], instance [MyIntegrationTest@546e61d5], exception [null]
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:161)
  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:681)
  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:563)
  at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
  at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_10120 table: MYTABLE column: MYCOLUMN
```

This seems to be correct, because indeed my code did not set the mycolumn atttribute in the entity before calling `persist` on it.

Questions:

- why database contraints are not checked during inserts but during commits?
- why when doing a rollback database contraints are not checked?

Comment: As HSQLDB does not have deferred constraints, they **are** checked when you run the insert or update statement. My guess is that your obfuscation layer (aka "ORM") does not send those statements right away but later when you try to commit. And of course it doesn't make sense to check constraints when your roll back a transaction because all changes that _would_ cause a constraint to fail are undone so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It is possible because, when I enable logging of queries and run the test with `defaultRollback=false` no queries are logged, when I run it with `defaultRollback=false` the queries are getting logged.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I think you are right. It seems to my lovely's Hibernate feature, inserts and updates are not sent until a commit or until a SELECT on non-cached entites. Thank you very much!

Comment: When using an ORM the queries are only flushed to the database when doing a commit (this is configurable). When no query is issued there is nothing to test. When a rollback is done nothing has been flushed and again there is nothing to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Posting @a_horse_with_no_name's answer, just to be able to close this question].

My ORM (Hibernate) was not sending queries to the database until a commit. If a transaction ended with a rollback the queries were not sent to the database at all. Making sure `flush()` is called (`FlushMode.ALWAYS`) after every `persis()` fixed the issue.